# Mouse Click coordinates - a true solution ... is there one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

There are, as of now, 3,898 posts in StackOverflow regarding mouse click coordinates. They all cover everything on how to find the coordinates for the mouse .... in relation to an element.

Has anyone been able to implement a solution where, at any point of your processing, you can recall the coordinates of the very last mouse click?

I have tried everything and every solution for the last 8 hours or so but cannot come accross anything that can recall the last mouse click coordinates.

Apparently, you have to catch it right where you are processing $('...').click(function(e){...});

How about if I sent the processing somewhere and, within that processing (a few nanoseconds later) I want to find out the coordinates of the last mouse click? How can I retrieve it outside an specific function?

EDIT:

Based on sdleihssirhc's suggestion, I was able to implement a solution that is working for me:

On the main page I have created two divs (to avoid dealing with arrays and global variables):

```
<div id='mouseX' style='display:none; ' ></div>
<div id='mouseY' style='display:none; ' ></div>
```

On the main page within the script tags:

```
$('#wrapper').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('#mouseX').text(e.clientX - offset.left);
    $('#mouseY').text(e.clientY - offset.top);
});
```

Whenever needed, I can just:

```
var clickX = $('#mouseX').text();
var clickY = $('#mouseY').text();
```

Thank you!

Comment: "How can I retrieve it outside an specific function?" Store the last mouse click coordinates in a variable outside the scope of the click event handler.

Comment: is there a reason you couldn't push each click coordinates into an array and then recall whichever one you wanted?

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer (and possibly accept it)?

Comment: Assuming you can only accept one answer, I felt I could not write my solution as an answer and, STILL, give credit to sdleihssihc; whom, as per my interpretation, gave me the right path to solve my own problem. Can one accept multiple answers?

Comment: _"On the main page I have created two divs (to avoid dealing with arrays and global variables)"_ - you say that as if it is a _good_ thing, but there is nothing wrong with using global variables for this purpose. Why do you think this way is better?

Comment: While an element (the divs) are objects, they cannot be changed throughout the entire processing. Global variables, as your project increase in size, becomes very volatile and then, to track where you are making the mistake can become hard.

Comment: Well, each to their own I s'pose, but if you give your variables descriptive names (and employ some simple namespacing techniques that you should be doing anyway to avoid conflict with any included libraries) then it shouldn't matter how big the project becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a global array, for keeping track of coordinates (maybe in an object, whatever). Then you can add an event listener to the document, listening for click. Then it's just a matter of logging the position.

Whenever you want to refer to the position during the last click, just refer to the appropriate element of your global array. (If your logging function unshifted instead of pushing, you could always just look at `yourArray[0]`.)

Comment: You have given some good ideas. Thanks! As far the appropriate element, if would be impossible for my problem as I am making a special function to handle results coming from other functions. But, definately, the "global holder" is a good idea.

Comment: @zequinha-bsb That's why you attach the click listener to the document: All click events (unless propagation has been stopped) will bubble up to it. (Or, if you use setCapture for IE, you can use event capturing and not [really] worry about propagation being stopped at all.)

Answer (score 0):

In the `$('...').click(function(e){...});` handler, you can set a global variable with the coordinates.  For example:

Globally:

```
var x = -1, // no previous click
    y = -1; // no previous click
```

In the click handler:

```
x = e.pageX();
y = e.pageY();
```

Then, you can just reference `x` and `y` when you need the coordinates of the last click.

Comment: I tried many variations of that. For whatever reason, the variables inside of the handler do not propagate. Even global variables (defined outside of the handler) could not regain the new values. That was a very interesting find. Thank you though!